# Exposing Diffie Hellman shared key in the logs for openssl lib

Tags: encryption, wireshark, diffie-hellman

In the openssl libarary there is a function called DH_Compute_key which will create the shared key.can we use it and expose it in the log for debugging purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. OpenSSL is opensource as you know - so just add some printfs there, rebuild it, and expose everything you need.